# Programmatically make keyboard go away

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, keyboard, uitextfield, first-responder

I made a text field but I didn't use Interface Builder, I did it programmatically in Xcode. So now I need a programmatic way to make it resign first responder so that the keyboard will go away when the user presses enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As addition to cobbal's answer, don't forget to set text field's delegate to the class that implements

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;    
}
```

Adding  descriptor to that class interface declaration is also a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

[docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/resignFirstResponder)

if you want it to go away when enter is pressed, you will need to implement

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

in your [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn%3a)

Answer (score 0):

I had this question my self and I realize that the above answer may not be what you're asking. My guess is you are adding UITextField as subviews to some view when you 'say double tap' (or some other event).  It is important to make a controller the delegate of that subview.

```
-(void)handleDoubleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
     //some other code creating the textfield 
     [aTextField setDelegate:self];
```

In this case I've used the controller itself.

Now inside that controller I can implement

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITxtField *)textField
```

and it will work.